# Image map alt tags not visible when disabling images

Tags: image, imagemap

Can anyone offer any pointers for making sure that the alt tags within an image map are visible when disabling images?

I am using the FireFox Developer toolbar to Replace Images with Alt attributes. All images  are replaced with the alt text that corresponds to them, but an image map does not.

Answer (score 0):

You should be putting the Alt tags on the AREA tags, not on the image.

```
<area href="#" shape="rect" coords="0,25,50,100" alt="A rectangle" />
```

Also try using Title attributes too.

- Oisin

Comment: I am using alt attributes within the area elements, but the alt text is not showing up.